# how to pass value of array in from 1st view to 4th view in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xml-parsing, nsarray

I have 4 views in my app namely
Year Published > Books > Author > author desc

I am getting this data through xml in this format.

So How do I pass the info in author desc depending on which book was selected and which author was selected ??
I have made an object name "result" containg all details of this parsed elements.Parsing is completely done. 
But I am not able to display and transfer information depending on the row selected from one view to the 3rd view.

Comment: Thank you from refraining from using all caps in the future... Please read the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, when you create the new view controller to push onto the screen (assuming you are using a uinavigationcontroller stack, sounds like you are), then set "result" as a property on the new controller

I'm guessing at the names of your viewcontrollers, also, I use the generic pointer type "id" for result, you can replace this with the specific class of result if you'd like.

YearPublishedViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BooksListViewController *booksVC = [[BooksListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BooksListViewController" bundle:nil];
    booksVC.result = self.result;
}
```

BooksListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BooksListViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) id result;
```

BooksListViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AuthorListViewController *authorVC = [[AuthorListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthorListViewController" bundle:nil];
    authorVC.result = self.result;
}
```

AuthorListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AuthorListViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) id result;
```

AuthorListViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AuthorDescriptionViewController *authorDescVC = [[AuthorDescriptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthorDescriptionViewController" bundle:nil];
    authorDescVC.result = self.result;
}
```

AuthorDescriptionViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AuthorDescriptionViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) id result;
```

AuthorDescriptionViewController.m

```
//use self.result wherever you need it here
```

Also be sure to release "result" in dealloc of each of these controllers for correct memory management.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. it seems perfect.But the data should pass according to the book I select. So should i use indexpath.row every tume ?

Comment: But still then suppose i pass with indexpath.row fro one view to another then i'll get the assocaited book object. But then afte that how to move forward with assocaited author in the same ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several commonly used practices and patterns to send messages and values between objects:

1. If you need to pass messages and/or values to objects in order of creation - use *`assignment`* or *`straight call`*. As well as **@obuseme** has already written.
2. If you need to pass messages and/or values to objects in backward order of creation - use *`delegation`*. "In backward order" I mean the owner creates its sub object and waits some callback from it.
3. Also there is a pattern named *`singleton`*. You can use it to have access to it from any of your objects.

Comment: I will strongly suggest using Singleton object. This will help alot if you decide to debug your application. check out this link for more information on singleton [link](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)

Comment: @lancegoh, Agree, but there is a disadvantage of Singleton. It is very hard to support it in multithread application.

Answer (score 0):

Inoder to pass value of array in from 1st view to 4th view then pass value from View1 to View2 and from there to View3 and from there to View4. This standard way of passing Value according to apple guidance

Comment: Hey, I am able to pass vaue from 1st to 2nd view but the thing is I have an object which stores all my values reagrding abook. so i only to pass the related value after each view.